# Groupby and Normalize selected columns Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a sample DF which I want to normalize based on 2 condtions

Creating sample DF:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,20,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
sample_df["date"]= ["2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01",
                "2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02"]
sample_df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df["date"])
sample_df.set_index(sample_df["date"],inplace=True)
del sample_df["date"]
sample_df["A_cat"] = ["ind","sa","sa","sa","ind","ind","sa","sa","ind","sa"]
sample_df["B_cat"] = ["sa","ind","ind","sa","sa","sa","ind","sa","ind","sa"]
sample_df
print (sample_df)
```

OP:

```
            A    B   C  A_cat   B_cat
date                    
2020-02-01  14  11   7   ind    sa
2020-02-01  19  17   3   sa     ind
2020-02-01  19  6    3   sa     ind
2020-02-01  3   16   5   sa     sa
2020-02-01  12  6    16  ind    sa
2020-02-02  1   8    12  ind    sa
2020-02-02  10  13   19  sa     ind
2020-02-02  17  2    7   sa     sa
2020-02-02  9   13   17  ind    ind
2020-02-02  17  16   3   sa     sa
```

Conditions to normalize:

```
1. Groupby based on index, and
2. Nomalize selected columns
```

For example if the selected columns are `["A","B"]`, it should first groupby index in this case `2020-02-01` and normalize the selected columns in the 5 rows of the group.

Other inputs:

```
selected_column = ["A","B"]
```

I can do this in a `for loop` by iterating over the groups and concatenating the normalized values. So any suggestions for a more efficient/pandas based approach would be great.

Code Tried with Pandas:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
dfg = StandardScaler()
sample_df.groupby([sample_df.index.get_level_values(0)])[selected_columns].transform(dfg.fit_transform)
```

Error:

```
('Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray=[14. 19. 19.  3. 12.].\nReshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.', 'occurred at index A')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
sample_df.groupby([sample_df.index.get_level_values(0)])[selected_column].transform(lambda x: (x-np.mean(x))/(np.std(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got your question right. Do you just want to group by index, select values from Aand B AND CALCULATE THE PERCENTAGE?

```
    sample_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    sample_df['date']=pd.to_datetime(sample_df['date'])
    sample_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    df2=sample_df[(sample_df['A']>10)&(sample_df['B']>5)]
    df2.groupby(df2.index.month)['A_cat'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

and if you want for all the rest of the columns excluding A and B. Please try

```
df2.groupby(df2.index.month).agg({i:'value_counts' for i in df2.columns[2:]}).groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x.div(x.sum()))
```

Alternatively, after selecting A and B into a dataframe, drop columns A and P and apply [pd.series value count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
df2.drop(columns=['A','B'], inplace=True)
df2.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).transform(lambda x: x.div(x.sum()))
```